# Convert PyQt4.QtGui.QImage object to base64 PNG data

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

How can I get raw base64 PNG data from a `PyQt4.QtGui.QImage object`? The only method I can find that seems like it would help is `bits()`, but that just returns a `sip.voidptr object` and I have no idea where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QImage` represents an image, not an image file. A `QImage` object cannot have PNG, JPG or other format. You need to save `QImage` to PNG format using `QImage::save`. It can be saved either to a file on disk or to any `QIODevice`. In this case `QBuffer` is a convenient IO device. It stores data in a `QByteArray`. After that we can use `QByteArray::toBase64` to get the result.

```
image = QImage(filename)
data = QByteArray()
buf = QBuffer(data)
image.save(buf, 'PNG')
print data.toBase64()
```

Answer (score -2):

You have the right method if you want to directly access the data in memory. It is a C array, and has no python object associated, so it's a little tricky. You need: the start address from bits(), the depth() and the byteCount(). ctypes.string_at would give you access to the data there, which you would pass to a numpy array using the known bits-per-pix and image shape.

I won't write more, because this kind of thing is likely to cause a crash (and I have no test data right now) - can you not load the image in the usual way?

Comment: The question asks about PNG data. It cannot be accessed from `bits()`.